# Para que serve o código "par = par + 1"?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h> 

int main(){ 

    int par=0, num, i; 
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
 
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++){
        printf("Informe número: "); 
        scanf("%d", &num);
            
        if (num%2==0){ 
            par=par+1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nQuantidade de números Pares: %d\n", par); 
    printf("Quantidade de números Impares: %d\n", 10-par); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esse Par serve como um contador de números pares.
Cada número par digitado, adiciona +1 na variável Par.

nesse caso, pode-se colocar também:

```
par += 1;
```

ou:

```
par++;
```

Comment: AAAAAAAA saquei, valeu irmão, nice.